# Background notifications not working on iOS with Flutter package firebase_messaging

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've come across many questions like this on StackOverflow and Github, but I haven't found the answer.

I have an Apple development profile, and I've uploaded APNs Auth Key to Firebase.

I have enabled Background fetch, Remote notifications and Background processing, as well as Push Notifications in my xCode.

I have added this two pieces of code to AppDelegate.swift:

```
import Firebase


if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
  FirebaseApp.configure()
}
    ...
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

  let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
    options: authOptions,
    completionHandler: {_, _ in })
} else {
  let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
  UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}

application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

I have added this line to Info.plist:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

I've also tried (not working as well):

```
key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>0</string>
```

I have followed the instructions from https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging and I get notifications when my app is in the foreground (onMessage is executed). However, I get no notifications at all when it's in the background. I've tried everything I could find suggested, nothing works. I am really desperate at this point. It doesn't work for the simulator or the real device. Can this even work? If so, please help me get it to.

Comment: I also had same issue few months back, but this article helped me  https://medium.com/@jun.chenying/flutter-tutorial-part3-push-notification-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-2fbdd84d3a5e

Comment: Great, I get the notification now! Thank you!!! The fix was to use key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>NO</string>

Answer (score 2):

As @ChyperX suggested, this article was helpful https://medium.com/@jun.chenying/flutter-tutorial-part3-push-notification-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-2fbdd84d3a5e. Using:

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>NO</string>
```

in **Info.plist** instead of my previous attempts did the trick.